# Finding the cost functional of a car-following model

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, models, non-locality

I have a car-following model with delay

$\ddot{x}_n(t)=\lambda [\dot{x}_{n-1}(t-T)-\dot{x}_{n}(t-T)]$,

where $\ddot{x}$ is the acceletation, $\dot{x}_{n-1}-\dot{x}_{n}$ is the relative velocity, $\lambda$ is the sensitivity and $T>0$ is the delay.

But I am intrigued by how I can construct the cost functional for minimizing travel time in the car-following model, where the friction between the car and the road, the structure of the road (if widened or it narrows, if there are curves, etc.). ) and climatic factors (if it rains, it snows, etc.)

Comment: Have you done a literature search on your own to see how others do it?

Comment: I have reviewed some books and document other problems of optimal control. But never just give you the dynamic and functional cost already built.

Answer (score 2):

If you are serious about your model, it would be prudent to use PID (Proportional-Integral-Derivative) control theory and diagrams. You do not have to use all the functions like the integrator but you need the full set of possibilities to be able to tune the system when you have performance or simulation data. Below is an example of a PID control system using the analogy of a driver trying to keep to the road ([from ref](https://www.jjrobots.com/pid/)). You can substitute 'Angle of Front Wheels' and 'how the angle of the front wheels...' with 'car speed' and 'how car speed affects the following distance' (affected by headwinds etc). You can also replace the 'driver's eyes' with a sensor such as a camera/LiDAR etc if you are going autonomous driving mode:
[image]

If you can pre-programme it to take into account road condition, road curvature, weather etc, then you would feed each factor as a modifier into one or a combination of the PID components. Sensors to ascertain road condition, curvature, weather etc would have to trigger the modifiers, of course. You can write out the equations for each block and sum (parallel components) or multiply (components in series) to create the complete control equation.

If you have a reinforcement learning system, it will work out the best combination of PID blocks as the car drives (with sensors giving feedback), or using realistic input-response data that you have.

With PID notation, the diagram looks like this ([ref](https://www.dewesoft.com/pro/course/pid-control-53)):
[image]